# How to change the FireBug representation of a css class with a FireBug extension?

Tags: css, firebug

When messing around in the FireBug css panel, you change the their representation of the original css file.  Like:

```
.myCssClass { width: 100px; }
```

However, if you add a jQuery line to this,

```
$(".myCssClass").css("width", "200px");
```

you end (of course) up with changing the style tag for this element and you see that your original width:100px has a strikethough in the FireBug representation.

So my question is, do you know a way to change the "original" width:100px instead of changing the style tag. I guess you have to through a FireBug extension to access that property, and that is not a problem for me.  But I don't know where to start :)

Edit: Have to point out that I am need to change the property by code! Either from a FireBug extension or somehow reload the corresponding css so that FireBug think it is the orginal value.

Comment: What's wrong with strikethough, Using jquery to change width value means your not changing the value permanently in your css definition, you are just manipulating the value for the session you are in.

Comment: Yes exactly, I have mede a FireBug extension that listens on your css changes. But that listener will not fire on style tag changes :/.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an old JS function that usually worked well for me (Before [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) and [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)).

Note that plain JS has security restrictions from accessing some stylesheets.  A FF add-on can get around that, but then you need to also beware of corrupting browser-chrome styles.

```
function replaceStyleRuleByName (sStyleName, sNewRule)
{
    var iNumStyleSheets = document.styleSheets.length;
    var bDebug          = 0;

    if (bDebug)     console.log ('There are ' + iNumStyleSheets + ' style sheets.');

    for (iStyleS_Idx=0;  iStyleS_Idx < iNumStyleSheets;  iStyleS_Idx++)
    {
        var iNumRules   = 0;
        var zStyleSheet = document.styleSheets[iStyleS_Idx];
        if (zStyleSheet)
        {
            /*---WARNING!
                This next line can throw an uncaught exception!
                Error: uncaught exception:
                     [Exception... "Access to restricted URI denied"  code: "1012"
                     nsresult: "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)"
                     location: ... ...]
            */
            //--- try/catch for cross domain access issue.
            try
            {
                var zRules  = zStyleSheet.cssRules;
                if (zRules)
                {
                    iNumRules   = zRules.length;
                }
            }
            catch (e)
            {// Just swallow the error for now.
            }
        }

        if (bDebug)     console.log ("Style sheet " + iStyleS_Idx + " has " + iNumRules + " ACCESSIBLE rules and src: " + zStyleSheet.href);


        //for (var iRuleIdx=iNumRules-1;  iRuleIdx >= 0;  --iRuleIdx)
        for (var iRuleIdx=0;  iRuleIdx < iNumRules;  ++iRuleIdx)
        {
            if (zRules[iRuleIdx].selectorText == sStyleName)
            {
                zStyleSheet.deleteRule (iRuleIdx);
                if (bDebug)     console.log (sNewRule);
                if (sNewRule != null)
                {
                    zStyleSheet.insertRule (sStyleName + sNewRule, iRuleIdx);
                }

                //return;   //-- Sometimes changing just the first rule is not enough.
            }
        }

        //--- Optional: Punt and add the rule, cold, to any accessible style sheet.
        if (iNumRules > 0)
        {
            if (sNewRule != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    zStyleSheet.insertRule (sStyleName + sNewRule, iRuleIdx);
                }
                catch(e)
                {// Just swallow the error for now.
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

**Sample Usage:**

```
replaceStyleRuleByName ('body',         '{line-height: 1.5;}' );
replaceStyleRuleByName ('#adBox',       '{display: none;}' );
replaceStyleRuleByName ('.BadStyle',    null );
```

Comment: Seems like that script replaces any existing property as well. What I need is that this modified call: replaceStyleRuleByName ('body', 'line-height: 1.5;' ); would add line-height to body and not to replace the existing properties for that css class.  (think)

Comment: Rather than making the code more complex to do that, I just include all the styles I want to keep in the second argument to `replaceStyleRuleByName`.   Note that you'd probably be better off using the Stylish extension, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on the property in question and then `edit [stylename]`

Comment: I think he wanted a programmatic way to that.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the "Computed" tab, it displays the actual values used of the properties of an element. The "Style" tab only displays the "stylesheet values" that affects a particular element, which may or may not be actually used by Firefox due to CSS' cascading rule and other layouting considerations.

[image: Screenshot of Firebug, showing computed tab]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that is now what I'm after. I have edited my question :)